# TYPO3 7.6.2 No Page Tree in Backend

Tags: typo3, updates, typo3-7.6.x

I updated my `TYPO3` from version **7.6** to **7.6.2**.

After clearing all caches etc (standard procedure) I have no pages in the page tree anymore. I checked the **php_log**, **error_log**, set `TYPO3` to debug modus...etc. No result, I've absolutely no idea. I tried it on my locale to. (also disabled all extensions)...

> origin it was a TYPO3 6.x.x -> than Updated to 7.6.0 (some months ago, everything was working) now the update to 7.6.2

Comment: I'm getting a JS error in the backend, when the page tree normally should be loaded

`Uncaught TypeError: this.textNode.setAttribute is not a functionExt.tree.TreeNodeUI.Ext.extend.onTipChange @ ext-all-debug.js:35933`

Comment: Problem also seen via http://typo3blogger.de/typo3-cms-6-2-17-und-7-6-2-veroeffentlicht/

Comment: Please do not post in German here.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use "stop page tree" in root templates. This will fix it!